# How do you fix TFS GUID names in TFS Analysis db after upgrade/migration?

Tags: tfs, analysis, warehouse

I upgraded and migrated TFS 2017 to TFS 2018 by moving Tfs_Configuration and Tfs_DefaultCollection only to a new DB server. I reconfigured Tfs_Configuration and Tfs_DefaultCollection in a new environment and rebuilt Tfs_Warehouse and Tfs_Analysis from scratch. Now reports are showing GUID names and not usernames. The GUID names appear to be users that are disabled in AD or have been deleted from AD and the metadata (user name) did not update as expected. Is there a way to update the GUID information with the users name?

I’m using Team Foundation Excel add-in to generate reports.

[image]

Comment: Hi, Please run the query in TFS2018 to check that the value of the field `assigned to` is GIUD or user name. "I upgraded and migrated TFS 2017 to TFS 2018 by moving Tfs_Configuration and Tfs_DefaultCollection only to a new DB server." Are you just moving the database tables to upgrade TFS2017?

Comment: Hi.  The report query above is from TFS 2018.  I setup a new environment (App Server 2016, Web Server 2016, DB Server 2016 with SQL 2017), backed up TFS db's from DB Server 2012R2 with SQL 2016, restored TFS db's (Configuration and DefaultCollection) to DB Server 2016 with SQL 2017, installed TFS 2017 in new environment, configured TFS 2017 in new environment with TFS db's on DB Server 2016 with SQL 2017 and then upgraded TFS 2017 to TFS 2018.  Then I setup reporting in TFS 2018 and created a new Warehouse and Analysis database.  Is there another query I need to run?

Comment: I rebuilt the TFS warehouse and cube and I still see GUID's and NULL's in the name field.

Comment: Where does the dimPerson table get its values from?  Name, SID, Domain, Alias, etc